# Google admin console use with github hosted website

Tags: github, google-workspace

I have purchased a domain through the google admin site (G suite), and I am trying to use it in conjunction with a page hosted on github. In google admin I have added a domain alias that is the url pointing to the github page I have hosted. And through github under the 'Github Pages' section of settings I have changed the custom domain to point to the purchased domain I have. But for some reason the webpage I have in my github repository is not displaying on the domain I have purchased. Instead when I navigate to the domain I have purchased, nothing displays, and when I go to the github url of my hosted page it reroutes me to my purchased url.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I set up http://jsonp.therobinkim.com/ to point to https://therobinkim.github.io/lets-learn-jsonp.

On GitHub, from https://github.com/therobnkim/lets-learn-jsonp settings, I put `jsonp.therobinkim.com` under my GitHub Pages `Custom domain` settings.

On Google Domains, from my custom domain's DNS settings, I added a new `Custom resource record`:

- `jsonp`, my custom subdomain (changed from default `@`)
- `CNAME`, bc we're pointing to another website by name instead of IP address (changed from default `A`)
- `1m` (changed from default `1h`, but not necessary)
- `therobinkim.github.io` (changed from placeholder `IPv4 address`)

It started working for me within 5 minutes.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a cname file on your github repository.  It is as simple as creating a file called `CNAME`, then putting your domain on it, i.e. `yourdomain.com`

Comment: actually this is already done by adding the domain to the Github Pages section, and I confirmed that it is there.

Comment: You might just need to wait a little while for the DNS to update. According to google, it can take up to 24 hours.

Comment: I considered that still, but I have waited ~48 hrs now.